# How to MOVE and RESIZE Features within a Layer?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-engine, toolbar

I am still new to ArcEngine 10, I currently am able to create a feature layer that is associated with a feature class. Its a polygon layer. So I can create polygon, give it attritbute table and put it on a layer using UNIQUEVALUERENDERER.

My question is, is there a tool bar control, or any way I can MOVE or RESIZE my polygon easily. I current use `"esriControls.ControlsSelectFeaturesTool"` to select the tools. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [IFeatureSelection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureSelection_Interface/0012000004ww000000/) to get the selected Feature(s).

Then cast [IFeature.Shape](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Shape_Property/002500000330000000/) to [ITransform2D](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000003w3000000), and call Scale, Move, etc.

Finally, call [IFeature.Store](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Store_Method/0025000007wv000000/) to save he changed geometry.

Comment: So if i want to do it that way, it is best I create a custom toolbar control to do this? Have the features I want move selected and use this NEW tool to Scale and move it?

Comment: You can also just use the toolbar control "esriControls.ControlsEditingVertexMoveToCommand"

Comment: Yes, if you want to just move individual vertices, that would be the way to go.